# Show UIActivityIndicatorView with JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I've been trying to show the `UIActivityIndicatorView` on app launch until the JSON finish getting the data from the website and then hide it(indicatorView). 
But I still couldn't figure it out! I'm using `UITableView` to show the downloaded data.

```
let kivaLoadURL = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json"
    var loans = [Loan]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getLatestLoans()

    }

func getLatestLoans() {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: kivaLoadURL)!)
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            self.loans = self.parseJsonData(data)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        })

        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Loan] {
        var loans = [Loan]()
        var error:NSError?

        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if error != nil {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        let jsonLoans = jsonResult?["loans"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonLoan in jsonLoans {
            let loan = Loan()
            loan.name = jsonLoan["name"] as! String
            loan.amount = jsonLoan["loan_amount"] as! Int
            loan.use = jsonLoan["use"] as! String

            let location = jsonLoan["location"] as! [String:AnyObject]
            loan.country = location["country"] as! String

            loans.append(loan)
            println("\(loan.name), \(loan.amount), \(loan.use), \(loan.country)")
        }

        return loans
    }
```

I used this following code to show the indicator, I tried to write after `self.tableView.reloadData()` to stop animating the indicator or hide alert but it didn't work, here is the code :

```
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Please wait...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel");
var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;
loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

alert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
alert.show();
```

Comment: you want to display the data in UITableView or not showing it?

Comment: the problem is to show the indicator while Json is getting the data and hide the indicator when the data is ready, I've loaded the data into the tableview but just to show the indicator .

Comment: Create and add `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` in `viewDidLoad` method and remove it from superview after you reloaddata of tableview in `parseJsonData` method

Comment: best way would be to set a buffer time and show the indicator for that time or the actual time for loading the data, whichever is more.

Comment: If you post your code which you have tried to show `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle`, then it would be easier to solve out problem

Comment: @Ghost but with different connection speed will be a not efficient !

Comment: @ViralSavaj , I've edited the question and explained better !

Comment: AS you updated your question, The indicator shows, but hide not work, right?

Comment: Yes Thats right , i tried to use  'self.indicator?.stopAnimating()' or to hide the alert but it stays.

Comment: Create variable outside of any method on top, like `var loans` declared on top, initialise where you want to start, then in put `loadingIndicator.stopAnimating` just before `return lone` in `parseJsonData` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variable on top like,

```
var categories = [String:String]()
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
let kivaLoadURL = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json"
```

Initialise it where you want to add like

```
var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;
loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

alert = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Please wait...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
alert.addSubview(loadingIndicator);
alert.show()
```

Just add line to hide alert before `return loan`

```
func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Loan] {
    ....
    alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: false)
    return loans
}
```

Try this, may help you.